# Exception doesn't be thrown to parent function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, try-catch

I use VS2012 for my project, I am handling the Socket exception when server cannot send message to target machine but It occurs that when It cannot send msg (I already put it in trycatch) Debugger just break in catch block and say the error without send forward to parent catch block. Please tell me, if I did something wrong.

```
    private void sendMessageToTarget(string Message, IPAddress targetAddress, int port)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(targetAddress, OUT_MESSAGE_PORT);
        Thread senderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect(server);
                MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
                NetworkStream netstream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] sentString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message);
                netstream.Write(sentString, 0, sentString.Length);
                memstream.Close();
                netstream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }));
        senderThread.Start();
    } // Sending Message Method
```

Above is my code for sending message to target

```
try
{
      sendMessageToTarget("CONN_CHECKER", target, OUT_MESSAGE_PORT);
}
catch (Exception se)
{
      ConnectedUsers.Remove(target.ToString());
      UpdateConnectedUserToTeacher();
      if (NeedFollowStudents.Contains(target.ToString()))
      {
          NeedFollowStudents.Remove(target.ToString());
      }
      UserLostConnection(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

And this is the method in another function that I want the action to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical marshalling exceptions from one thread to another. It is even *almost* guaranteed that code after `senderThread.Start();` will be executed before code in the thread's delegate.

You function that you pass to `Thread` constructor becomes top level function on a new thread. If such function throws exception (like you do) this exception will go to [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event and than normally terminates application.

Your options

- revert to synchronous code (all code on one thread)
- use existing asynchrnous methods that will notify your code about end of operation. Depending on approach notification can be either via event (similar to [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202.aspx) ) or via callback and calling EndXXXXX like Socket.BeginSend
- use [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)
- manually implement synchronization and marshalling exception to original thread.

Note that only synchronous version of the code will work the way you want, all other that use multiple threads will not be able to return exception to the same "parent function" (using `async` will at least allow your code look the way you want even if it will not work the same way).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I believe you should only put a Try/Catch in the parent function and not in the child. When the exception occurs it will show in the parent method. The way you have it written will catch the exception in the child method and it will not get passed back to your parent method.

Comment: I tried to do that, but debugger just stopped on line >>>> client.Connect(server);